# access to session in sub project with asp.net mvc

Tags: session

i have one web application project in asp.net mvc

and another programmer write root project with asp.net 
in my project i must reading session of root project but i don't know how ?
my project is virtual of root project but not in one solution 
i dont access to root code project 
but i know session key in root project is ["UserInformation"]

i use this code but didn't work

```
  public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.Session["UserInformation"] != null)
        {
            SiteUser user =(SiteUser)filterContext.HttpContext.Session["UserInformation"];
            CoustomerDetail.UserId = user.UserId;
            CoustomerDetail.Name = user.FirstName;
            CoustomerDetail.LastName = user.LastName;

            using (UserLogBussinessRole repsRole = new UserLogBussinessRole())
            {
                UserLog currentUserLog = repsRole.SetLoginAndLogout(CoustomerDetail.UserId, true);
                CoustomerDetail.LastLogin = currentUserLog.LastLogin;
                CoustomerDetail.LastLogout = currentUserLog.LastLogout;
            }

            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        }
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect("http://tahlildadeh.com/Users/Login.aspx", true);
    }
```

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two applications cant share session variables in "InProc" mode. Since your virtual directory is basically a different application, so it's not possible to access the session value. In order to share state between multiple applications, you have to use "out-of-proc" session storages that includes "State Server" or "SQL Server" (or manually implementing a state storage).